# Making a query in MS Access

Tags: t-sql, ms-access, vba

I am having a problem with my query. I have 2 tables:

Table 1 is `AutoCompany` it has fields `company` and `CodeCar`. `CodeCar` can be 3 or 4 depending on the type of car that company has.

table 1: AutoCompany

```
company| CodeCar|  
  jora     3
  jora     4
  jora     3
 ghita     3
 ghita     3
 ghita     4
gheorghe   4
gheorghe   3
gheorghe   3
```

Table 2 `CodeCarCompanies` has the codes:

```
car | codeCar
mers    3
vW      4
```

I need to select the companies with the count of the occurance of the 2 `codeCar`s
resulting in something like this:

```
   company  | MERS| VW
   jora        2     1
   ghita       2     1
   gheorghe    2     1
```

My attempt so far:

```
 SELECT     COUNT(dbo.AutoComany) AS MERS, dbo.Company, COUNT(dbo.AutoComany.     
 [CodeCar]) AS VW,  

   FROM   dbo.AutoComany FULL OUTER JOIN
                  dbo.AutoComany  ON dbo.АВТОМОБ.КодПредпр = AutoCompany.company
     WHERE     (dbo.CodeCarComapnies.[CodeCar] = 3)
    GROUP BY dbo..company, dbo.CodeCarComapnies.[CodeCar]
    HAVING      (dbo.CodeCarComapnies.[CodeCar] = 4)
```

Comment: Are you using SQL Server with MS Access or are you just using MS Access?

Comment: i revised the question a bit, i hope i made the correct assumption for your wanted reultset

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In MS Access, I think you want:

```
SELECT codecarcomapnies.car,
       Count(autocompany.codecar) AS CountOfCodeCar
FROM   autocompany
       INNER JOIN codecarcomapnies
               ON autocompany.codecar = codecarcomapnies.codecar
WHERE  autocompany.codecar  IN ( 3, 4 )
GROUP  BY codecarcomapnies.car;
```

The above was built using the MS Access query design window and the Sum `Σ` button

Edit re Comment

```
SELECT Sum(IIf([autocompany].[codecar]=3,1,0)) AS mers, 
       Sum(IIf([autocompany].[codecar]=4,1,0)) AS vw
FROM autocompany
```

Or

```
TRANSFORM Count(autocompany.CodeCar) AS CountOfCodeCar
SELECT "Total" AS Total
FROM autocompany 
INNER JOIN CodeCarComapnies 
ON autocompany.CodeCar = CodeCarComapnies.codeCar
WHERE autocompany.CodeCar In (3,4)
GROUP BY "Total"
PIVOT CodeCarComapnies.car
```

Comment: i need that in ome field it will count codecar number 3 and in another codecar number 4

Comment: I have added some extra notes.